# How to get a function to repeat over several created divs

Tags: javascript

I have a function that creates a random genre of music, that is then put into a created div. Currently there are 12 divs, but when it runs, it only adds in the random genre into the first div, and not the others. I've tried making a for loop to go through each one but it's not firing, for some reason. When I console.log it, I see 12 random genres, but only the first is getting inserted into the div. Here's the code:

```
function displayArtists(artistsData) {
    let artists = artistsData;
    let artistsHTML = '';

    let music = ["Rock", "Metal", "Rap", "Hip-Hop", "Pop", "Swing", "A capella", "Soul", "Classical", "Jazz", "EDM", "Techno"]
    let random = Math.floor((Math.random() * music.length));
    let final = music[random];

    //     Creates Random Genre of Music
    
    function genre(){
        let randomGenre = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.random-genre'));
        for (i = 0; i < randomGenre.length; i++) {
        randomGenre.innerHTML = final;
        console.log(final);
        }
    }
    
    artists.forEach((artist, index) => {
        let name = artist.name;
        let city = artist.location.city;
        let state = artist.location.state;
        let picture = artist.picture;

     
        //      Creates the HTML Container

        artistsHTML += `
            <div class="randomContainer" data-index="${index}">
                <div class="randomArtistInfo">
                    <div class="randomArtistHold">
                        <h5 class="name">${name.first} ${name.last}</h5>
                        <h6>${city}, ${state}</h6>
                        <h6 class="random-genre">--ehhh--</h6>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="containerRandomImg">
                    <img src="${picture.large}" class="roundImg">
                </div>
            </div>
        `           
        
    });
    randomDiv.innerHTML = artistsHTML;
    genre();
}
```

And here's the guthub. Keep in mind, it's meant for mobile view only so far, and isn't finished.
https://github.com/JTLovato/projectHelp

Comment: I'd hazard a guess that `randomGenre[i].innerHTML = final;` might be what you're looking for? But for any real help you need to share enough of your relevant [mcve] code that you're working with, in order that we can reproduce your problem as closely as possible. (Just the minimum relevant code, and please [edit] it into your question, don't post it in the comments.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
randomGenre.innerHTML = final;
```

Creates the property innerHTML and assigns it the value in final.
It does that randomGenre.length times.

You need to use [i] to dereference the array and set the innerHTML of the element.

Try this instead.

```
    for (i = 0; i < randomGenre.length; i++) {
    randomGenre[i].innerHTML = final;
    console.log(final);
    }
```

If you want a each div to have a different value you'll need to put the genre selection in the loop so that it's reset each iteration.

```
    for (i = 0; i < randomGenre.length; i++) {
        let musicIndex = Math.floor((Math.random() * music.length));
        let genre = music[musicIndex];
        randomGenre[i].innerHTML = genre;
    }
```

Comment: This does almost what I need, however it takes the randomed genre and applies it to all of the divs, so if came up with Rap, all the divs have Rap in them...

Comment: if you want different genres then you need to pick a new genre each iteration of the loop. See edits.

Answer (score 0):

As the other posters noticed, it's about the assigment of `final` to the `randomGenre`.

I found a solution which is to just make a function that returns the genre div (instead of trying to update it with your `genre` function after the fact).

This appears to do what you want.

```
const artistsData = [
  {name:'one'},
  {name:'two'}
]
const randomDiv = document.getElementById('random')

function displayArtists(artistsData) {
    let artists = artistsData;
    let artistsHTML = '';

    let music = ["Rock", "Metal", "Rap", "Hip-Hop", "Pop", "Swing", "A capella", "Soul", "Classical", "Jazz", "EDM", "Techno"]
    let random = Math.floor((Math.random() * music.length));
    let final = music[random];
    let genreDiv = 
      `<h6 class="random-genre">${final}</h6>`
  

    //     Creates Random Genre of Music
    
    
    artists.forEach((artist, index) => {
        let name = artist.name;

    
        artistsHTML += `
            <div class="randomContainer" data-index="${index}">
                <div class="randomArtistInfo">
                    <div class="randomArtistHold">
                        <h5 class="name">${name}</h5>`
                        + genreDiv + `
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        `           
        
    });
    randomDiv.innerHTML = artistsHTML;
}

displayArtists(artistsData)
```

You'll notice I made a trim set of artistData just to try it out and see it work.
But hopefully this helps.

Comment: Hmm. When I run it, it says it can't set property innerHTML of null at displayArtists.

Comment: oh right - i did this in a code pen where i set `randomDiv` to pull a div with `id=random` (see at the beginning of my code snippet).  that should be replaced with whatever you had for the place where all this ends up.  Your code snippet did not specify *how* you found the `randomDiv` so i'd added that just to prove out the solution.